# Postgres jsonb select specific array fields

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have PostgreSQL 10.2 table "snapshots" with jsonb column named "data"

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "userName": "John",
      "age": "15"
    },
    {
      "userName": "Max",
      "age": "42"
    }]
}
```

Need a query to select only userNames from entries in the array.
I tried this

```
select data->'entries'->>'userName' from snapshots;
```

but of course it's not returning values that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unnest the json array with the function [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) used in a lateral join:

```
select item->>'userName'
from snapshots
cross join jsonb_array_elements(data->'entries') as item
```